# Flutter TTS stop function does not work properly on Web

Tags: flutter

Flutter TTS 3.7.0 in a web environment where playing and stopping the TTS results in an error, and subsequent attempts to play don't work.
--> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts/example

Use Sample code of https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts/example
Run on Chrome web.
Use any sample text.
Select US language.
Play.
Before finishing the speak push stop button.
Replay does not work ==> Play shoud work again.
Run time error log ==> Error: Expected a value of type 'JsObject', but got one of type 'SpeechSynthesisEvent'
PS) flutter tts 1.0.0 works properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.